# Java String Split with delimiters attached to the characters between demiliters

Tags: java, regex, split

I have String like

```
Client Name:##USERNAME## Age:##AGE## xyzed
```

I want to Split is like this

```
[Client Name:][##USERNAME##][ Age:][##AGE##][ xyzed]
```

I tried this regex `(?=(##(\\w+)##))` it returned

```
[Client Name:][##USERNAME## Age:][##AGE## xyzed]
```

as in java look-behind doesn't work with variable length so can not use

```
(?=(##(\\w+)##))|(?<=(##(\\w+)##))
```

Comment: Have you tried `(##(\\w+?)##)`

Comment: @EugenRieck If you mean without the look-around, with using split, that will completely remove `##USERNAME##` and `##AGE##` from the output, which is not desired. If it's just adding the `?` you mean, I don't think it will make any difference, since `#` isn't part of `\w`, and there are spaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy with a giant hard-coded upper limit, this will work:

```
(?=##\\w+##)|(?<=##\\w{1,1000}##)
```

(I also removed some of those excess brackets)

This:

```
String string = "Client Name:##USERNAME## Age:##AGE## xyzed";
String regex = "(?=##\\w+##)|(?<=##\\w{1,1000}##)";
String[] arr = string.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Prints:

```
[Client Name:, ##USERNAME##,  Age:, ##AGE##,  xyzed]
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/k2MZRN).

Here's an alternative, but it may be too specific to the input:

```
(?=##\\w)|(?= )(?<=##)
```

[It also works](https://ideone.com/Tmjbjj).

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, and just involves global replaces:

```
String Name = "Client Name:##USERNAME## Age:##AGE## xyzed";
String[] parts = Name.replaceAll(":##",":@##").replaceAll("## ",":##@ ").split("@");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(parts));
```

Prints:

```
[Client Name:, ##USERNAME:##,  Age:, ##AGE:##,  xyzed]
```

It's quite simple to read, but it's probably **slower** than Dukeling's answer.